# Auto save adds two empty lines between comment and function header in Python in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, pylance

I write code in Python in VS code. If I add comment before function and hit save button, VS code adds two empty lines:

```
# comment


def MyMethod():
    return 0
```

In settings I see that I use autopep8 formatter:
[image: autopep8 formatter]

I wasnt able to find what causes this annoying issue.  Maybe I can configure settings somewhere?

Comment: You could use something like autopep8 or black? Usually, vscode asks you about the formatter you'd like to use, you can use wither of auto pep8 or black

Comment: @AmartyaGaur I added some details in post edit. I figured out I use autopep8 but where are the settings?

Comment: It is fairly common to put the comment on top of the code. I did try a few --ignore tags to make your style work, but it seems not to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment documenting function behavior should be placed inside function, just below signature.
If it is not describing function (is placed outside function) it should have those blank lines.
Don't mess with language's conventions, it's very bad idea.

**Edit,** Further clarification:

```py
"""Module-level comment
"""


def function(): 
    """Function level comment. 
    There are multiple conventions explaining how
    a comment's body should be formed.
    """
    return 0
```

Comment: Oh, i didnt knew that. So it should be:

def MyMethod():
# comment
    return 0

As I understand?

Comment: Close, but you should be using triple quote strings """content""" as documentation in the function body, because of convention and the fact that they can be retrieved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the code convention (PEP8) of Python. Pylance will correct your code when saving. 
This is an excerpt of PEP8 which you can find [here](https://pep8.org/#comments):
`You should use two spaces after a sentence-ending period.`

If the comment describes your function, try using Docstrings.

Comment: Docs strings also causes two empty lines to be added

Answer (score 0):

Add `--ignore=E302,E265` to `python.formatting.autopep8Args` can also be an alternative way to ignore the extra two lines between the outer layer comment and code. The downside is that it **would not** correct the right number of lines between two functions anymore.

[similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366234/vscode-python-formatting-autopep8-disable-e266)